# Magento 2 How to display placeholder image to image preview backend UI component form

Tags: uicomponent, image-upload, magento2.3, ui-form, image-preview

In my custom module i have custom UI component form and i add file upload filed to this form.

Form is working fine while Add or Edit, when upload file image preview is display,but i want to display default image preview once file is not uploaded and display a placeholder image to image preview section.

Below is image upload code.

```
<field name="image">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">string</item>
                <item name="source" xsi:type="string">image</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Image</item>
                <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">fileUploader</item>
                <item name="placeholderType" xsi:type="document">document</item>
                <item name="elementTmpl" xsi:type="string">ui/form/element/uploader/uploader</item>
                <item name="previewTmpl" xsi:type="string">Namespace_Modulename/image-preview</item>
                <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                </item>
                <item name="uploaderConfig" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="url" xsi:type="url" path="managelabels/productlabel/upload"/>
                </item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </field>
```

After search a lot and found something to display placeholder image [this link](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/ui_comp_guide/components/ui-fileuploader.html). in this documentation they use `placeholderType` argument to Defines the preview type.

But i have no idea to how to implement this argument to my custom form.

Any help would be appreciated!Thanks

Comment: change document to image

Comment: `<item name="placeholderType" xsi:type="image">image</item>`

Comment: and integration https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/ui_comp_guide/components/ui-fileuploader.html#integrate-fileuploader-component-with-form-component

Comment: 1 exception(s):
Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException): The XML in file "/var/www/html/Projectname/app/code/Namespace/Modulename/view/adminhtml/ui_component/namespace_modulename_form.xml" is invalid:
Element 'item', attribute '{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance}type': The QName value 'image' of the xsi:type attribute does not resolve to a type definition.
Line: 205

Comment: might change it to string `<item name="placeholderType" xsi:type="string">image</item>`

Comment: I also try with different attribute like string, array, number, image but no luck :)

Comment: how about `<item name="placeholderType" xsi:type="document">image</item>` ?

Comment: still not. actually i tried so many way and i think i have to go with customization.